# Why does my draw method only work some of the time?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I know that in swing you are meant to use repaint to redraw a panel, but I am starting to make games and have read that repaint is unreliable in terms of timing.  So I am trying to make a strategy where I create a BufferedImage, draw every thing I need to that objects graphics object and then draw the image to my jpanel using drawImage method.

I am calling dispose to get the panel to re-render, but its only working some of the time.  The following is just an example.  If you keep running this program, the BufferedImage only gets drawn ~3/10 times you run it.  Can someone explain this to me please?

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setLocation(50, 500);
    jf.add(mp);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);

    mp.draw();
}
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d;

public MyPanel() {
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
}

public void draw() {
    System.out.println("In draw");
    g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    g2d.drawString("Test", 10, 10);

    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    g.dispose();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("In paintComponent");
}

}
```

What am I battling with here behind the scenes that is blocking the draw more often than not.  I realise that resizing the window, etc. will call repaint and override my drawing but when I don't do that it should show up every time, no?

Edit: interesting... if I wrap the draw method in a continuous while loop it "works".  But this doesn't answer my question.  I shouldn't need to constantly recall the method to give the illusion that it's drawing ok.

Comment: before `jf.setVisible(true);` try adding `jf.revalidate();jf.repaint();`

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Nope.  Same result.  Draws every few times of running.

Comment: Invoke `draw()` method after frame is shown. (Inside WindowOpened action, I suggest..)

Comment: I would recommend reading chapter 2 of Killer Game Programming in Java (recommend the whole book actually): http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch1/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the getGraphics() method to do painting. Any code you do with getGraphics is only temporary and will be lost whenever Swing determines the component needs to be repainted, which is probably happening here.

Override the getPreferredSize() method of your class and invoke super.paintComponent() and then add a System.out.println(...) statement. Also, add a System.out.println(...) statement to the draw() method to see the order of execution of the code.

> I am calling dispose to get the panel to re-render,

That won't cause the panel to render, it just frees the resources allocated to the Graphics object. You need to invoke the draw() method to continually repaint.

This is essentially the same as using a Timer to continually repaint() the component. The difference is the that the draw() might happen right away, but the repaint might take a few milliseconds. But since repaint() takes a few ms every time the interval will remain constant, its not like repaint will paint once and then wait a second the next time.

Comment: Hi, I am quoting the book "Killer Game Programming in Java" which encourages the use of getGraphics to draw, and not rely on repaint and overriding paintComponent()....

"The call to repaint( ) is gone, as is the overriding of paintComponent( ); its functionality
has been incorporated into paintScreen( ).
Active rendering puts the task of rendering the buffer image to the screen into my
hands. This means that the rendering time can be accurately measured, and concerns
about repaint requests being delayed or skipped by the JVM disappear"

Comment: Also, you are correct, dispose only frees resources.

Comment: You asked for an explanation of your problem, which I provided. Did you verify the result by adding the System.out.println(...) statements?

Comment: Yes, I can see draw is called every time when I add in a print statement.  Sorry, I don't think it answers my question.  If it does then I don't understand it.  Why does it draw some of the time (and stay there) and not all the time?

Comment: Did you override paintComponent() with a print statement? My answer was that Swing is scheduling normal painting and the default painting for a panel is to clear the background and this code is executed after your draw method.

Comment: It is also a timing issue. Swing components should be created on the EDT. You can get random results. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. As a solution, override the paintComponent() method with your painting code, then you invoke that method directly. Then whether you invoke the method or Swing invokes the method you image gets painted. That is the only statement in the paintComponent() method should be the drawImage() statement. Your draw() code would just update the image.

Comment: Yes I added a print to overriden paintComponent and draw method.  The program always prints out the following in this order:

In draw
In paintComponent
In paintComponent

but actual drawing outcome is always the same.  Gets drawn every few times.

Comment: If "in paintComponent" is always last then you should never see anything. If "in Draw" is last then you will see your painting. If that is not the behaviour, then I can't explain. Read the tutorial link I provided. If code is not created on the EDT you can get random results.

Comment: "If "in paintComponent" is always last then you should never see anything." - right, but sometimes I am.  Run the program for yourself and see.  Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just back from golfing (fore!!) and tested my suggestion to use the EDT and painting is as expected. The paintComponent() method is executed last and always clears the painting done by the draw() method.

Comment: Strange that draw is executed last given the draw method is called after add,pack,etc.

Comment: I assume you mean strange the paintComponent() is executed last. Not really, The repaint() request is handled by the RepaintManager which consolidated paint requests and adds them to the end of the EDT for processing. See [Painting in Swing (and AWT)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#mgr) for more information. Anyway, your question (about the cause) has been answered. As I suggested the problem was your code did not execute on the EDT so order execution was random. The answer should be accepted so people know the question has been answered.

Comment: My code is on the EDT now and the result is still the same.  I wish Oracle would fix the Painting in Swing (and AWT) page; the code examples don't display correctly in any browsers for me.

Comment: The code worked fine for me (10 out of 10) when I invoke the code in the main() method on the EDT. That is paintComponent() is output last and the frame is always clear. I'm using JDK 7 on Windows 7. Update your question that show the code that is causing the problem when you use the EDT. A `SSCCE` should be included every time you make a statement that something doesn't work. Then we can run the code and compare. Maybe you did something wrong, maybe it is a version platform issue.

Comment: Also, better structure the SSCCE so that it is a single file to copy/paste. We don't want multiple source files lying around. So add the main() method to your MyPanel class.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code and got the following GUI:

[image]

When you paint on a buffered image, you have to do everything.  You have to paint the background and paint the foreground.

When you paint the buffered image in the paintComponent method of a JPanel, all you have to do is draw the image.

The Swing paintComponent method is fast enough in Java versions 6, 7, and 8 to paint without flickering.  I've done animations with tens of thousands of lines with no flicker.

You must start a Swing application on the Event Dispatch thread by calling the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.

Here's your modified code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestMain implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocation(50, 50);
        jf.add(mp);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        mp.draw();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestMain());
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d;

        public MyPanel() {
            super();
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("In draw");
            g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawString("Test", 30, 50);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("In paintComponent");
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gilbert.  Dang, I completely overlooked running the program on the EDT!  Thanks.

"The Swing paintComponent method is fast enough in Java versions 6, 7, and 8 to paint without flickering. I've done animations with tens of thousands of lines with no flicker." - this is good to know, as I have read that it isn't good enough.

Comment: @AlanSmith, `I completely overlooked running the program on the EDT!` I mentioned that in my comments and gave you the link to the Swing tutorial. This answer still doesn't explain the random behaviour, it only demonstrates normal Swing painting. You can still have timing issues since the RepaintManager consolidates repaint() requests and adds the request back onto the EDT. So if your game handles lots of KeyEvents for example this could theoretically slow down the repaint cycle. I think this is the type of timing issue the book is talking about.